# burstable instances in standard mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Does the following mean that cloudformation is not supported if I need to change t4g to standard mode for burstable instances?

> You can launch your instances as unlimited or standard using the
> Amazon EC2 console, an AWS SDK, a command line tool, or with an Auto
> Scaling group.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-how-to.html

Comment: Please Edit your question to tell us more about why you are mentioning CloudFormation. Also, tell us whether the instances were originally launched via CloudFormation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-how-to.html) does not mean that CloudFormation is not supported. You are always better to check [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) documentation addressing that type of questions.

I created an EC2 Instance with `unlimited` mode that comes by default

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: 't4g.medium'
      SubnetId: 'subnet-07cc83847cb184254'
      SecurityGroupIds: ['sg-0a8d1090cfb961220']
      ImageId: 'ami-0006abfd85caddf82'
```

then updated the Stack adding [CreditSpecification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance-creditspecification.html):

```
      CreditSpecification:
        CPUCredits: 'standard'
```

and it updated perfectly.

Comment: I am using AWS::EC2::SpotFleet and I do not see that parameter is supported.

Comment: It is advaisable using `savings plans`. Spot is an old-fashion way of saving on AWS.